# Want to plot curve from points and want to remove axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Actually want to draw this curve exactly but dunno how to plot it from the points and can't remove the axis values

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid style=dashed,
] 
\addplot[color=blue]
    coordinates {
    (-6,10)(-5,9.5)(-4,8.4)(-3,6.8)(-2,4.75)(-1,2.3)(0,0)(1,2.3)(2,4.75)(3,6.8)(4,8.4)(5,9.5)(6,10)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{phonon-4}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Please help me thanks a lot

Comment: how to add code properly i don't know that sorry and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is to remove the tick labels: `xticklabels={},yticklabels={}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,axis y line=middle,
    grid=both,minor grid style={densely dotted,gray,ultra thin},
    minor xtick={-2.5,-1.5,...,2.5},minor ytick={0.1,0.3,...,0.9},
    xticklabels={},yticklabels={},trig format=rad]
    \addplot[color=red,domain=-pi:pi,smooth,samples=51] {abs(sin(x/2))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]